# A value from template's form parameters is not passed in View

Tags: html, django, forms, django-views

I have a student that is using `django` framework to build an app.

She has a template that contains a slider. The part of this form in the template is:

```
<form  method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="slidecontainer">

    <input name="range" type="range" min="{{ beginframe }}" max="{{ endframe }}"  onclick="sLider.oninput();" class="slider" id="range">
    <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
    <button type="button" class="button4"  name="showframebtn" id="showframebtn" >Show frame</button>
</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="fname1" value="{{video_path}}" style=" margin-top: 15px; margin-left: -45px;width: 410px; height: 40px;">

</form>
```

Next, she needs to handle the value of the slider and the `{{video_path}}` value. This is her code a function in views.py:

```
elif request.method == 'GET' and 'f' in request.GET:


        if framenumber:
            print(framenumber)
            fname_1 = request.GET.get('fname1')
            print("fname", fname_1)
```

However, the value of hidden input parameter is not passed. The value she gets is `None`.

Using the `page source` from the browser we can see that indeed the hidden parameter has a value.

```
<form  method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="slidecontainer">

    <input name="range" type="range" min="1" max="11"  onclick="sLider.oninput();" class="slider" id="range">
    <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
    <button type="button" class="button4"  name="showframebtn" id="showframebtn" >Show frame</button>
</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="fname1" value="C:/Users/Username/PycharmProjects/thesis/static/3/actual_video.avi" style=" margin-top: 15px; margin-left: -45px;width: 410px; height: 40px;">

</form>
```

Can you please help us on how to fix this? Is this due to the fact that she is using a button parameter?

Thank you in advance!

The full function code from views.py can be found here:

```
def video_analysis(request):

    framenumber = request.GET.get('f', '')
    print("framenumber ", framenumber)

    global frame2
    global tmp_path
    global myfile
    global filename
    global img1
    global img2
    global video_table, motionFlow_table
    video_table = []
    angles =[]
    motionFlow_table = []
    video_table = np.empty([30, 400, 400, 3], np.dtype('uint8'))
    motionFlow_table = np.empty([30, 400, 400, 3], np.dtype('uint8'))
    times =0

    if (request.session['doctor_id'] == ""):
        return redirect('login')

    times = times +1
    path = STATIC_PATH
    direct = request.session['directory']
    p_id = request.session['p_id']
    p_name = request.session['p_name']
    p_lastname = request.session['p_lastname']
    os.chdir(direct)
    print(direct)


    myfile = None
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'myfile' in request.FILES:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = myfile.name
        print(filename)
        if (not os.path.exists(direct + "\\" + myfile.name)):
            filename = fs.save(direct + "\\" + myfile.name, myfile)
            print(filename)
        path = direct + "\\" + myfile.name
        print(path)
        print(direct)
        request.session['path'] = path
        request.session['file'] = myfile.name
        print(myfile.name)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename) + "/static"
        print(uploaded_file_url)
        if request.session.has_key('path'):
            path = request.session['path']
            tmp_path = ""
            for i in range(0, len(path)):
                if (path[i] == "\\"):
                    tmp_path = tmp_path + '/'
                else:
                    tmp_path = tmp_path + path[i]


        print(tmp_path)
        print(myfile)
        if myfile != None:
                print("not empty")
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(str(myfile))

        if (cap.isOpened() == False):
            print("Error opening video")

        begin_frame = 1
        count =1 #counter for frames
        ret, frame1 = cap.read()

        # Region of Interest - ROI
        template = frame1[150:250,0:100]

        video_table[count] = frame1  # save the video into array
        cv2.imwrite(('frame %d.jpg' % count), frame1)
        original = frame1
        grayimg_1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imwrite('frame1gray.jpg', grayimg_1)

        gray_img, topleft, bottomright = template_matching(grayimg_1,template )
        print("topleft",topleft)
        print("bottomright",bottomright)

        cv2.imwrite("gray1.jpeg", grayimg_1)

        if np.shape(frame1) == (): 
            print ("empty frame")

        hsv = np.zeros_like(frame1)
        hsv[..., 1] = 255



        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
        fourcc1 = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
        out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 25.0, (500, 400))
        out1 = cv2.VideoWriter('output1.avi', fourcc1, 25.0, (500, 400))

        while (cap.isOpened()):
            ret, frame2 = cap.read()
            count =count+1

            if ret != True:
             break;

            video_table[count] = frame2  # save video frames into table
            cv2.imwrite(('frame %d.jpg' % count), frame2)
            grayimg_2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            cv2.imwrite("gray %d.jpeg", grayimg_2)

            gray_img, topleft, bottomright = template_matching(grayimg_2, template)


            # Computes a dense optical flow using the Gunnar Farneback's algorithm.
            flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(grayimg_1, grayimg_2, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)

            test_img = draw_flow(gray_img, flow,topleft,bottomright)
            cv2.imwrite(("motionFlow_img %d.jpg" %count), motionFlow_table[count])


            # Calculate the magnitude and angle of 2D vectors.
            mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[..., 0], flow[..., 1])


            angles.append(ang)

            k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
            if k == 27:
                break

            cv2.imwrite('opticalfb.jpeg', frame2)
            grayimg_1 = grayimg_2

        print("number of frames: ", count)
        out.release()
        out1.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


        cv2.waitKey(0) #press something to continue
        end_frame = count


        # Video Properties
        # number of frames
        video_length = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
        total_frames = int(video_length)
        print("total" , total_frames)

        #frame rate
        frame_rate = float(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
        print(frame_rate)
        #video duration
        duration = round(float(video_length / frame_rate), 2)
        print(duration)


        data = np.array(ang)
        name_of_file1 = filename.split("/")[-1]

        name_of_file1 = p_id + "/" + "frame 1.jpg"
        print(name_of_file1)

        return render(request, 'video_analysis.html', {     'video_frame' : name_of_file1,
                                                            'firstframe' : name_of_file1,
                                                            'video': myfile,
                                                            'video_path':tmp_path,
                                                            'beginframe': int(begin_frame),
                                                            'endframe': int(end_frame),
                                                            'video_duration': duration})
```

Comment: Are you sure that `video_path` is not `None` ?

Comment: You could inspect the form using Chrome/Firefox developer tool and see the actual value in that hidden field. As @shotgunner said, please check if it's not `None`.

Comment: @shotgunner Yes, we have checked it via page source.

Comment: @zinon show full code of your views that send those context variables like `video_path` and `beginframe`.

Comment: @shotgunner I added it right know. I also added the html code from `page source`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I think is that you have `method="GET"` set on your form, but you're encoding the form as `multipart/form-data`. Data encoded as `multipart/form-data` is split into multiple parts and cannot be sent in the URL using GET.

If you want the form to make a GET request, then you should remove the `enctype="multipart/form-data` from the form. This will cause the form to send the data using the default encoding which can be sent in the URL.

Alternatively, if you wish to use `multipart/form-data` you should change the form method to `method="POST"`. If you do that, you'll also need to modify your view:

```
elif request.method == 'POST' and 'f' in request.POST:
    ...
    fname_1 = request.POST.get('fname1')
```